# Python downgrade after conda install 'package' not showing up in python --version

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, datashader

I've been trying to install a particular package - [datashader](https://github.com/pyviz/datashader) . Steps followed -

```
> python -m venv dashshader #my spelling mistake wrote data->dash 
> cd dashshader
> Scripts\activate.bat

(dashshader) > conda install datashader
# list of packages to be downloaded ...
# Package to be installed datashader:0.6.6-py36_1
# list of packages to be updated ...
# The following will be downgraded: 
      anaconda:       custom-py37_0           --> custom-py36h363777c_0
      python:         3.7.0-hea74fb7_0        --> 3.6.7-h33f27b4_1
```

Based on above downgrade info I assumed my python will be downgraded in this virtual environment. But that didn't happen.

`(dashshader) > conda list` listed all the packages above including dashshader. Yet when I did `import pandas as pd` it failed. Also `(dashshader) > python --version #3.7.0-hea74fb7_0`.

But when I made a new env and did
`(newenv) > pip install datashader` , another bunch of packages installed, and `python --version` is `#Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda custom` and my package imports are good.

When I do `pip list` in the older enivronment, I get an `AssertionError: SRE Module mismatch`. Although my problem is solved with `pip`; I have very little idea about what's going on. Clearly `conda` took up some immutable space related to `sre_compile.py` But I don't understand why it didn't downgrade Python after saying it will downgrade python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\..\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\SaralJoshi\Desktop\Notebooks\venv\dashshader\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\..\lib\re.py", line 123, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "C:\..\Anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
```

Comment: I don't reckon it's a good idea to mix `venv` and conda...

Comment: I just saw that my normal command line python is also downgraded to `3.6.7`

Comment: What OS are you on? Regardless, if you use conda for you virtual environments, you should be using `conda create`, not `python -m venv`.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit

Comment: Are you using the Anaconda Prompt or regular cmd? Anaconda Prompt is used when running conda on Windows.

Comment: Using Regular cmd

Comment: 1. You should be using Anaconda Prompt. 2. You should not be mixing `venv` and `conda`. Use `conda create` to create environments.